# Installing Xen: choosing a host, seeking tutorial

Tags: virtualization, xen

I want to install Xen on my PC, but I don't know where to start.

Basic usages:

- Install two OSs (Linux, Ubuntu or Fedora), one for Database server, one for HTTP server (PHP).
- Install one Windows 7 for Windows programs.

But my problem is I don't know which Linux distribution to use as my host OS. Which Linux is best suited for Xen? I googled it and I think OpenSuse is more friendly with Xen.
And do I have to compile the Kernel?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an awesome tutorial for everything xen at [book.xen.prgmr.com](http://book.xen.prgmr.com/mediawiki/index.php/Chapter_1:_Xen:_A_High-Level_Overview). The guys that wrote it run a vps service using fully open source xen. They use centOS for the tutorial dom0 because of its stable development path and its compatibility with xen.

Comment: Do you have a direct link to the tutorial? The link above goes to an overview of Xen, which is chapter 1 of the book it's from.

Comment: @pthesis... it is chapter 1 of 15, don't be afraid to read a little. Click on the link for "next chapter" at the bottom of the page to see other more "hands-on" chapters. http://book.xen.prgmr.com/mediawiki/index.php/ is the link to the wiki home page with links to the book buried further in. I don't know about a "direct link".

Comment: http://wiki.prgmr.com/mediawiki/index.php/Briefcontents is the contents page.